# EditorForMany not working for objects deeper than 1 level

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an example asp.net mvc5 program in which I'm trying to build a payment model with many levels of partials added to make a complete object.  In this example, I am using generic data.  I have a top level 'testing', to which you can add multiple 'A1' objects, and to that you can add multiple 'B2' objects.

The form uses ajax and jqueryto allow the person to add data on the fly, which is then submitted all at once when the submit button is pressed.

I found an [html helper](http://www.mattlunn.me.uk/blog/2014/08/how-to-dynamically-via-ajax-add-new-items-to-a-bound-list-model-in-asp-mvc-net)  made by [Matt Lunn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/444991/matt) that does an editorForMany.  It works very well, adds all my info to the web page, but it will never post back a model that is deeper than 2 levels(top, with a1's attached).

I can get the entire model to build on my page.  It looks appropriate, but when I post back, nothing under A1 shows up.  I can add as many 'A1's as I want.  If I change the code and put 'B2's directly under testing, that will work, but nothing will add under the 'A1's as I have it.

Here is my code.  I apologize for the formatting and the length of this post.

MVC helper

```
 public static MvcHtmlString EditorForMany<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, IEnumerable<TValue>>> propertyExpression, Expression<Func<TValue, string>> indexResolverExpression = null, bool includeIndexField = true) where TModel : class
{
    var items = propertyExpression.Compile()(html.ViewData.Model);
    var htmlBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    var htmlFieldName = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(propertyExpression);
    var htmlFieldNameWithPrefix = html.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(htmlFieldName);
    Func<TValue, string> indexResolver = null;

    if (indexResolverExpression == null)
    {
        indexResolver = x => null;
    }
    else
    {
        indexResolver = indexResolverExpression.Compile();
    }

    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        var dummy = new { Item = item };
        var guid = indexResolver(item);
        var memberExp = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(Expression.Constant(dummy), dummy.GetType().GetProperty("Item"));
        var singleItemExp = Expression.Lambda<Func<TModel, TValue>>(memberExp, propertyExpression.Parameters);

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(guid))
        {
            guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            guid = html.AttributeEncode(guid);
        }

        if (includeIndexField)
        {
            htmlBuilder.Append(_EditorForManyIndexField<TValue>(htmlFieldNameWithPrefix, guid, indexResolverExpression));
        }

        htmlBuilder.Append(html.EditorFor(singleItemExp, null, String.Format("{0}[{1}]", htmlFieldName, guid)));
    }
    MvcHtmlString m1 = new MvcHtmlString(htmlBuilder.ToString());
    return m1;
}
```

testing Controller

```
public class testingController : Controller
{
    // GET: testing
    public ActionResult startTest()
    {
        var model = new testing();
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult startTest([Bind] testing model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var r = 1;
        }

        return View(model);

    }

    [OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]
    public ActionResult addA1()//current running test 
    {
        var model = new testing();
        model.aas.Add(new A1());
        return View(model);
    }

    [OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]
    public ActionResult addB2()//current running test 
    {
        var model = new A1();
        model.bbs.Add(new B2());
        return View(model);
    }

}
```

model class

```
public class testing
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<A1> aas { get; set; }
    public testing()
    {
        aas = new List<A1>();
    }
}
public class A1
{
    public string aName { get; set; }
    public List<B2> bbs { get; set; }
    public A1()
    {
        bbs = new List<B2>();
    }
}
public class B2
{
    public string bName { get; set; }
    public B2() { }
}
```

startTest.cshtml

```
@model proofOfConceptPaymentBuilder.Models.testing
@{
ViewBag.Title = "startTest";
}
@section Scripts
{
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
$('#add-bbs').on('click', function () {
jQuery.get('/testing/addB2').done(function (html) {
$('#bbsList').append(html);
});
});    
$('#add-aas').on('click', function () {
jQuery.get('/testing/addA1').done(function (html) {
$('#aasList').append(html);
});
});     
});
function alertSomething() {
alert('something');
jQuery.get('/testing/addB2').done(function (html) {
$('#bbsList').append(html);
});
};
</script>
}
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<h2>Create</h2>
@Html.EditorFor(x => x)
<input type="submit" />
}
```

EditorTemplates
(testing editor template)

```
@model proofOfConceptPaymentBuilder.Models.testing
<div class="form-group">
@Html.LabelFor(x => x.name)
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.name)
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<div id="aasList">
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.aas)
</div>
    <input type="button" id="add-aas" value="add aas" />
    <input type="button" id="delete-testing" value="delete test" />
</div>
```

(a1 editor template)

```
@model proofOfConceptPaymentBuilder.Models.A1
<div class="form-group">
@Html.LabelFor(x => x.aName)
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.aName)
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<div id="bbsList">
    @Html.EditorForMany(x => x.bbs)
</div>
<input type="button" id="add-bbs" value="add bss" onclick="alertSomething()"/>
<input type="button" id="delete-aas" value="delete ass" />
</div>
```

(b2 editor template)

```
@model proofOfConceptPaymentBuilder.Models.B2
<div class="form-group">
@Html.LabelFor(x => x.bName)
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.bName)
</div>
<div>
<input type="button" id="delete-bss" value="delete bbs" />
</div>
```

addA1.cshtml

```
@model proofOfConceptPaymentBuilder.Models.testing
@{
     Layout = null;
}
@Html.EditorForMany(x => x.aas)
```

addB2.cshtml

```
@model proofOfConceptPaymentBuilder.Models.A1
@{ 
    Layout = null;
}
@Html.EditorForMany(x => x.bbs)
```

Ok, so I'm sorry for the formatting.  I'm kinda new to the formatting here.  I had to manually indent my code for it to show up in code blocks.

Comment: The helper works similar to the [BeginCollectionItem](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BeginCollectionItem/) in that it adds a `Guid` indexer, and that also only works one level deep. You could take a fully client side approach (which gives better performance, but is a bit harder to maintain if you ever change the model properties or its attributes) as shown in [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wqE6Rb)

Comment: Thank you!  That is exactly the answer I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

I also stumbled upon this problem and, given the number of questions I have found here in StackOverflow dealing with similar problems, I have created a .NET Core library to solve exactly this. It is called [DynamicVML (Dynamic View-Model Lists)](https://dynamic-vml.github.io/) and you can get it with NuGet.

It is basically a list templating engine for ASP.NET Core, that you can use to display lists of view models of any depth.

You can use it like this:

```
@Html.ListEditorFor(x => x.Addresses, 
    Url.Action("AddAddress"), // the action in your controller that creates views
    "Add new address", // some text for the "add new item button" in your form
    listContainerTemplate: "viewThatWrapsTheList", 
    listTemplate: "viewForTheList",
    itemContainerTemplate: "viewThatWrapsYourViewModel",
    ItemTemplate: "viewForYourViewModel")
```

Now, you do not actually have to specifiy all of this. If you want you can do just

```
@Html.ListEditorFor(x => x.Addresses, Url.Action("AddAddress"), "Add new address")
```

And it will guess all the rest.

It will support nesting with any depth, as it was the core of the question.